# How to Remove/Disable Scrool Bar in Quick Action When i click

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I want to add button and disable scroll bar and also increase width. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Is it a standard quick action or a lightning component built by you? Please provide more details.

Comment: So, you want to make it so the user can't see the rest of the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a custom button inside the quickAction modal, you need to implement the interface:

> force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader

This will give you a blank modal. The only thing you need to do is write your custom head and footer.

If you need to hide the back modal (By default, if you put your custom modal inside the quick action, the original modal its still in the window), at this moment you can use this code:

```
<aura:html tag="style">
    .slds-spinner_container{
        background: transparent !important;
    }

    .modal-body {
        background: transparent !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }
    .slds-modal__header--empty {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .modal-container{
        width: 90% !important;
        max-width: initial !important;
    }
</aura:html>
```